# Python: How to get multiple elements inside square brackets

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, match, python-2.7

I have a string/pattern like this:

```
[xy][abc]
```

I try to get the values contained inside the square brackets:

- xy
- abc

There are never brackets inside brackets. Invalid: `[[abc][def]]`

So far I've got this:

```
import re
pattern = "[xy][abc]"
x = re.compile("\[(.*?)\]")
m = outer.search(pattern)
inner_value = m.group(1)
print inner_value
```

But this gives me only the inner value of the first square brackets.

Any ideas? I don't want to use string split functions, I'm sure it's possible somehow with RegEx alone.

Comment: have you checked `m.group(2)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`re.findall` is your friend here:

```
>>> import re
>>> sample = "[xy][abc]"
>>> re.findall(r'\[([^]]*)\]',sample)
['xy', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("\[(.*?)\]", "[xy][abc]")
['xy', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you're looking for [**`re.findall`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

See [this demo](http://ideone.com/EVVEy5):

```
import re
my_regex = re.compile(r'\[([^][]+)\]')
print(my_regex.findall('[xy][abc]'))
['xy', 'abc']
```

If you want to iterate over matches instead of match strings, you might look at [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) instead.  For more details, see the [**Python `re` docs**](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Comment: Shouldn't you escape inner ] ?