# Split at multiple delimiter without delimiter in the list

Tags: python, regex, split

This should be an really easy task using the `re` library. However, I can't seem to split my string at the delimiters `]` and `[`.

I already read [Splitting a string with multiple delimiters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393157/splitting-a-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python), [Python: Split string with multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters), and [Python: How to get multiple elements inside square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403275/python-how-to-get-multiple-elements-inside-square-brackets).

My string:

```
data = "This is a string spanning over multiple lines.
        At somepoint there will be square brackets.

        [like this]

        And then maybe some more text.

        [And another text in square brackets]"
```

It should return:

```
['This is a string spanning over multiple lines.\nAt somepoint there will be square brackets.','like this', 'And then maybe some more text.', 'And another text in square brackets']
```

A short example to try:

```
data2 = 'A new string. [with brackets] another line [and a bracket]'
```

I tried:

```
re.split(r'(\[|\])', data2)
re.split(r'([|])', data2)
```

But those would either result in having the delimiter in my resulting list or a wrong list altogether:

```
['A new string. ', '[', 'with brackets', ']', ' another line ', '[', 'and a bracket', ']', '']
```

Result should be:

```
['A new string.', 'with brackets', 'another line', 'and a bracket']
```

As a special requirement all newline characters and white spaces before and after a delimiter should be removed and not be included in the list either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> re.split(r'\[|\]', data2)
['A new string. ', 'with brackets', ' another line ', 'and a bracket', '']
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a simpler approach than the non-capturing groups I recommended.

Comment: Works great. Just as an addition: How would I remove all newline characters und white spaces at the end/beginning of an element?

Comment: Ok. Figured it out. Using `strip()` on each element in the list. Thanks again.

Comment: @cherrun How about `re.split(r'\s*[\[\]]\s*', data2)`

Answer (score 5):

As arshajii points out, you don't need groups at all for this particular regexp.

If you did need groups to express a more complex regexp, you could use noncapturing groups to split without capturing the delimiter. It's potentially useful for other situations but syntactically messy overkill here.

> (?:...)
>
> ```
> A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.
> ```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

So the unnecessarily complex but demonstrative example here would be:

```
re.split(r'(?:\[|\])', data2)
```

Answer (score 2):

use this instead (without capture group):

```
re.split(r'\s*\[|]\s*', data)
```

or shorter:

```
re.split(r'\s*[][]\s*', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Couuld either split or findall all, eg:

```
data2 = 'A new string. [with brackets] another line [and a bracket]'
```

Using split and filtering out leading/trailing spaces:

```
import re
print filter(None, re.split(r'\s*[\[\]]\s*', data2))
# ['A new string.', 'with brackets', 'another line', 'and a bracket']
```

Or possibly, adapt a findall approach:

```
print re.findall(r'[^\b\[\]]+', data2)
# ['A new string. ', 'with brackets', ' another line ', 'and a bracket'] # needs a little work on leading/trailing stuff...
```