# Regex between two characters - last occurence of first char and first occurence of last char

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to capture all the occurrences between two characters for example `"["` and `"]"`. However, I need the last occurrence of the first character and the first occurrence of the last character. Meaning that:

> hello I'm [ a tricky [ test ] and another one [ here ]. goodbye

should return `[ test ]` and `[ here ]`.

I've tried this: `/\[(.*?)\]/g` but it returns: `[ a tricky [ test ]` and `[ here ]`.

Comment: Use `\[([^\][]*)\]`

Comment: The regex is provided in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9403327/3832970

Comment: @MrMysteryGuest Not sure what you mean, [it matches all that is necessary.](https://regex101.com/r/zdpfDr/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my mistake. I thought the op was after a regex looking for brackets within brackets, not pairs.