# Regex for Text Between Brackets and Text Between Semicolons

Tags: python, regex

I have the following shape of string: `PW[Yasui Chitetsu]`; and would like to get only the name inside the brackets: `Yasui Chitetsu`. I'm trying something like

```
[^(PW\[)](.*)[^\]]
```

as a regular expression, but the last bracket is still in it. How do I unselect it? I don't think I need anything fancy like look behinds, etc, for this case.

Comment: Actually your problem is the other way around. This regex matches `asui Chitets`

Comment: See [Python: How to get multiple elements inside square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403275) and [Regular expression to extract text between square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122)

Comment: It looks like you can massively simplify the regex to `PW\[(.*)\]` which will match `Yasui Chitetsu` in this case

Comment: @DeepSpace, `PW\[(.*)\]` is giving me the full `PW[Yasui Chitetsu]` in Python and when I try it in Atom. Are you using some other standard for Regexs?

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro If you are using `match` or `search` you should then get the first group, ie `re.match(r'PW\[(.*)\]', 'PW[Yasui Chitetsu]').group(1)`

Comment: @DeepSpace, you're right, your solution also works, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The Problems with What You've Tried

There are a few problems with what you've tried:

- It will omit the first and last characters of your match from the group, giving you something like `asui Chitets`.
- It will have even more errors on strings that start with `P` or `W`. For example, in `PW[Paul McCartney]`, you would match only `ul McCartne` with the group and `ul McCartney` with the full match.

## The Regex

You want something like this:

```
(?<=\[)([^]]+)(?=\])
```

Here's a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/dc7kw4/1).

## Explanation

`(?<=\[)` means that the match must be preceded by `[`

`([^]]+)` matches 1 or more characters that are not `]`

`(?=\])`means that the match must be followed by `]`

## Sample Code

Here's some sample code (from the above regex101 link):

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(?<=\[)([^]]+)(?=\])"

test_str = "PW[Yasui Chitetsu]"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

## Semicolons

In your title, you mentioned finding text between semicolons. The same logic would work for that, giving you this regex:

```
(?<=;)([^;]+)(?=;)
```

Comment: Why so complicated? `PW\[(.*)\]`

Comment: Nice, thank you very much.The semicolons thing was a similar problem in another code. The tutorial you've mentioned also seems very helpful.

Comment: @DeepSpace Because OP didn't specify that the `PW` was necessarily constant or that there is only one such group in the string. My example is general. Your example would break on, for example, `AB[Yasui Chitetsu]` or `PW[Yasui Chitetsu] something PW[Another Name]`. Better to err on the side of being more precise.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro Glad it helped! Please remember to accept the answer. :)

Comment: Both solutions will work in my case (there are in fact some lines with different prefixes before the brackets), but Ed's seems better indeed. Thanks to you two.

Comment: @EdCottrell: I think you are right. You taught me a little about regexes I did not know yet (I don't use them very often, but might use them more, now). Thanks.